# Setting/unsetting keyboard focus

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, focus

Trying to implement a simple HTML editor TextBox. I have a UserControl with a `Canvas` as main container and a `TextBox` and `ListBox` as its children. The ListBox is invisible by default. When user presses `CTRL + SPACE`, the ListBox should appear at TextBox's current caret position and focus should be transferred to it, just like Visual Studios's **List Members** feature. User then selects an item from the list and presses `ENTER` and the selected item is inserted into the `TextBox`. The `ListBox` then becomes invisible again and focus transfers back to the `TextBox`.

The following code lets me do all of the above; almost. It only works for the first time! The next time I press `CTRL + ENTER`, the `ListBox` appears and seems to have focus too, but pressing down (or up) arrow moves focus back to the `TextBox`, thus moving the caret instead. What's wrong here?

```
private void txt_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Space && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        var Rect = txt.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(txt.SelectionStart , true);
        Canvas.SetLeft(lst, Rect.Right);
        Canvas.SetTop(lst, Rect.Bottom);

        lst.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        lst.Focus();
    }

}

private void lst_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        txt.Focus();
        lst.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        txt.SelectedText = lst.SelectedItem.ToString();
        txt.SelectionStart += lst.SelectedItem.ToString().Length;
        txt.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, because I've wanted to see how something like this was done

Comment: +1 for making an usable test example

Comment: I have a feeling that this has something to do with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.directionalnavigation(v=vs.100).aspx. Digging more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to duplicate your problem, It appears that the focus in not being assigned to your listbox and is remaining in the TextBox. I was able to get it to work by using the textbox's MoveFocus Method. Though this is dependent on the actual tab order of your controls.

```
txt.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

In reference to your comment, I did notice that and worked around it by making sure that I set the Listbox's selectedIndex to -1

```
lst.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: Where do you put this line?

Comment: Replace your lst.Focus

Comment: Now that's some help. Thanks a bunch. But this brings up at least a couple of questions. 1. Did you notice the problem that when the ListBox appears second time, although it highlights the previously selected item, the real focus is on the first item. 2. Do we call this behavior a bug or "feature"?

Comment: Nice, better than my solution toggling txt.Focusable

Comment: I was able to work around that by setting  the list's selected Item to -1 i.e. `lst.SelectedIndex = -1;`

Comment: Right and that's trivial, but somewhat unexpected I guess. Thanks anyway. You saved me some headaches.